Spring @Async architecture for scheduled, long running api calls
I need to solve the following problem, described exemplary:
My Spring application checks every minute if there is a new job. If there is a job, it subtasks should be run in parallel. They are mostly done "somewhere else" and are depending on API-calls. They run between 10 minutes and several hours. These API-calls have authentication in the form of Bearer-tokens with a lifetime of an hour so we need to be able to renew them.
When all the subtasks are done some (individual) transformations have to be done and then the result gets saved.
My current approach is to have Scheduler run every minute and run an @Async function which looks likes this:
CompletableFuture<Result> subtask1 = subtaskService1.performTask()
             .thenCompose(subtaskService1::transfrom)

CompletableFuture<Result> subtask2 = subtaskService2.performTask()
             .thenCompose(subtaskService2::transfrom)

CompletableFuture<Result> subtask3 = subtaskService3.performTask()
             .thenCompose(subtaskService3::transfrom)


CompletableFuture.allOf(subtask1, subtask2, subtask3).join()

saveResult(subtask1.get(), subtask2.get(), subtask3.get())

The performTask-methods are @Async as well and mostly handle logic:

get a valid auth token if there is none or the current one is no longer valid
start a process
a while loop that checks the status of the remote task and if it is still ongoing it waits for two minutes via Thread.sleep(). This is not @Async
if the status is complete it gets the result and returns with CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() or CompletableFuture.completedFuture()

Now I run in some unexpected problems:

Sometimes (not every time) I get "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking error" from the WebClient when I get a new token. Right now this logic is implemented like this:

WebClient.builder()
...
.filter((request, next) -> next.exchange(withBearerAuth(request)))
...

where the withBearerAuth makes a synchronous WebClient-call (different instance) to get a new Bearer-token if the old one is expired.

The multi-threading is very confusing to me. Sometimes the threads in the logs use the prefix I configured in the Executer in my Spring Async Configuration. Sometimes it uses "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-x" and sometimes something like "parallel-x". Where is the difference? Is this a symptom of something going wrong?

lastly no matter how many threads I configure as a CorePoolSize the number of parallel task is lower than I would have expected. Even if I configure a CorePoolSize of 10 and have only 3 different subtask they don't always run in parallel. Do I have to programmatically "free" threads?

Are VirtualThreads something I should look into?



Some observations:

tasks run for minutes, not milliseconds
multi-threading is confusing

Given these observations, we can take it slow and stick to a simple threading model: ditch anything that has reactive/flux in it, stick to plain "Spring MVC". Replace WebClient with a synchronous (blocking) client (e.g. RestClient). And keep it simple: refresh the Bearer-token every time before it needs to be used in a separate call.
This should fix 1) and 2). CorePoolSize (3) is only used to set a minimal amount of threads that are ready to execute work, it has no impact on the maximum amount of threads being used (new threads will be created as needed).
Virtual threads are (properly) supported in Spring Boot 3.2 and up with Java 21, but they will not help you with your current issues. However, if you need your application to use less resources (and be a bit faster), you can switch to using virtual threads (i.e. configure Spring Boot to use virtual threads with possibly some minor changes to your application code). That is kind of the beauty of virtual threads: your "old school" blocking code (using lots of expensive platform threads) suddenly becomes as efficient and performant as non-blocking reactive-style solutions without the downside of those solutions. But any (logical) issues in your current code cannot be solved by switching to virtual threads. In fact, the use of virtual threads may even highlight some of the logical issues that exist in your current code since execution becomes faster and more parallel (e.g. giving rise to race-conditions you did not know existed).
